# Remove all lines from a .txt file, except for lines beginning with specific word

Tags: c#

I am attempting to create a program that will read all lines from a text file and remove all text, except for the lines beginning with 'Line 1:, Line 2:, Line 3:' etc.

```
UPDATE
```

Thank you for all your suggestions. Here is the final working code:

```
//PROCEDURE
        private void Procedure()
        {
            // READ AND APPEND LINES
            var file_path = @"Tags.txt";
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file_path))
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^Line\s+[0-9]+:") || (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^Zeile\s+[0-9]+:") || (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^Linea\s+[0-9]+:"))))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(line);
                }
            }

            // SAVE BACK
            File.WriteAllText(file_path, sb.ToString());
        }

        private void btnRefine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Procedure();
        }
```

Any improvements to the code are always welcome.

Comment: The issue here is that you don't describe what you want to do with these lines later - are you printing on the screen? Saving to another file? Forwarding that to another function?

Comment: I am new to C# so in terms of looping through the text and appending the lines, I am not sure how to do this. I don't need to use the lines later, but have only the lines beginning with 'Line 1:' remain in the text file. Perhaps re-writing them to a separate file would be easier.

Comment: u cant modificate files directly in this way u have to write a new file and then rename it to the old one when u want remove things, change file would work only in binary mode when u replace the cotnent with the exact amount of same bytes. So in ur Case it would be easy to make a new List/Array and put them into a new file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is all you need: `File.WriteAllLines(file_path, File.ReadAllLines(file_path).Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "...") || Regex.IsMatch(line, "...") || ...));`

Comment: Thank you Lasse, this has made it very simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
void ProcessFile()
{
    var file_path = @"Tags.txt";
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file_path))
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^Line\s+[0-9]+:"))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    // Save back
    File.WriteAllText(file_path, sb.ToString());
}
```

#### UPDATE

You could use LINQ instead. Then the previous code will look like this:

```
void ProcessFile()
{
    var file_path = @"Tags.txt";
    File.WriteAllLines(file_path, File.ReadLines(file_path).Where(line => !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^Line\s+[0-9]+:")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your suggestion, This has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After getting all lines as a List you can simply use RemoveAll to remove lines like this,

```
List<string> lines = new List<string> (File.ReadAllLines("Tags.txt"));
lines.RemoveAll(line => !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^Line\s+\d+:");
using (StreamWriter fw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("TagsNew.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)))
{
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
       fw.WriteLine(line);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help. At first, I actually missed the point of pattern you specified (Line 1, Line 2 etc). So, I have updated code to remove words occurring in pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) and [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) to do the file IO.  They are convenient in that they allow you to easily use LINQ-style operations on all the lines of a file.  This comes at the cost of the entire file being read into memory -- which may not be practical for a file that is many GB in size.

The LINQ `Where` clause would allow you to filter lines according to a predicate of your choosing.

The criteria for keeping a line is that it starts with your `Line 123:` pattern.  That can be articulated using a regular expression like  `^Line\s+\d+:`.  Which basically calls for the line to begin with `Line` followed by some whitespace, followed by some digits, then a colon.  [Regex.IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_IsMatch_System_String_System_String_) will allow you to test to see if each line matches the regular expression.

Here's a one-liner:

```
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", File.ReadAllLines("input.txt")
    .Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^Line\s+\d+:")));
```

Comment: *This comes at the cost of the entire file being read into memory -- which may not a practical for a file that is many GB in size.* That's why one needs to use `File.ReadLines` 

Comment: @JohnyL, You're absolutely right.  Also, if you don't want to store the entire remaining portion of the file in memory, then you should not use a `StringBuilder`, nor should you use `File.WriteAllText`.